# Java web service in .NET proxy class returns null

Tags: java, .net, soap

When I access a Java web service in a .NET proxy class, I get the reply string as null.

With the help of SOAP extensions, I found that this is the reply that I get from the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
         <getInfoResponse xmlns="http://services">
             <getInfoReturn>
                 <full_Name xsi:nil="true"/>
             </getInfoReturn>
         </getInfoResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the client class that i am using

```
cardInfo = new global::CardInfoService.CardInfoService.CardInfoService(); 
card = cardInfo.getCardInfo(value, number); 
System.Console.WriteLine("Got the Card Holder name " + card.full_Name);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post some of your code or the service WSDL?

Comment: @Andre I am trying to create a console application   ' cardInfo = new global::CardInfoService.CardInfoService.CardInfoService();    
                card = cardInfo.getCardInfo(value, number);    
                System.Console.WriteLine("Got the Card Holder name " + card.full_Name);'

Comment: Have you added a service reference by referencing the WSDL?

Comment: @Andre I had added the "Web Reference". The name of the web reference is CardInfoService..

Comment: Edit your question and add some code of the service class/wsdl and the client